lgpio GPIO.setup fails with 'GPIO not allocated' when run from a flask app
I've a flask webserver on a Raspberry Pi 5 that I'm using to control a motor via the GPIO pins. This was working fine, but has now stopped for reasons that I'm trying to get to the bottom of.
Running the motor standalone works fine, however when I try and run it from the flask app, using the following code:
from flask import Flask

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
P_SERVO = 0 # GPIO port
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(P_SERVO, GPIO.OUT)
pwm = GPIO.PWM(P_SERVO, 50)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello world'

# Commenting the below line does not trigger: lgpio.error: 'GPIO not allocated'
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')

It fails with:
 * Serving Flask app 'test'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://192.168.1.160:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/fufarm_hydro/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    GPIO.setup(P_SERVO, GPIO.OUT)
  File "/opt/fufarm_hydro/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/RPi/GPIO/__init__.py", line 704, in setup
    initial = _check(lgpio.gpio_read(_chip, gpio))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/fufarm_hydro/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lgpio.py", line 903, in gpio_read
    return _u2i(_lgpio._gpio_read(handle&0xffff, gpio))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/fufarm_hydro/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lgpio.py", line 458, in _u2i
    raise error(error_text(v))
lgpio.error: 'GPIO not allocated'

Can anyone suggest why it's different when run from Flask?

You need to change from RPi.GPIO to a library based on libgpiod on Bookworm. RPi.GPIO is no longer supplied or supported.

When you run flask in debug it forks itself ("Restarting with stat") and, as you request a GPIO line at global scope, that will try to request the GPIO line for the second time.  A line can only be requested by one process at a time, so the second attempt fails.
Have you tried running without debug=True?:
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

Or preventing the module being reloaded when it forks:
app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False, host='0.0.0.0')

or, as per this answer, inhibit the GPIO initialisation until after the reload:
from flask import Flask

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os

if os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN") == "true":
    P_SERVO = 0 # GPIO port
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(P_SERVO, GPIO.OUT)
    pwm = GPIO.PWM(P_SERVO, 50)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
 return 'Hello world'

app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')

Each of those options work for me.

That's brilliant. Thanks @Kent - I had a feeling it was something to do with an extra instance being started but didn't know enough about Flask to work out where that was happening.

If you have a Pi5 you CAN NOT use RPi.GPIO.
It is unclear WHY it is in your code which asks about lgpio.

Thanks @Milliways. RPi.GPIO was installed by Adafruit Blinka and I actually changed my code from using that to trying the calls it was using directly, to try and see what the problem was. Would that indicate that Blinka is installing the incorrect packages? The strange thing is that it works if I comment out the app.run line, so RPi.GPIO does work on a Pi 5, even if it shouldn't!

I can't comment on Adafruit Blinka; I did once try to install it to see what their Circuit Python did but the instructions  were vague (as usual with Adafruit) and obviously hadn't been updated for python3.11.

If it did install a shim I can't for the life of me understand WHY they didn't give it a different name - it is confusing; whenever I clone a library I give it a distinct name. If people can't change 1 include statement to use a shim they probably shouldn't. Many of the RPi.GPIO functions would be meaningless and have no counterpart in lgpio.
